# A regex to validate an email

Tags: php, mysql, regex, expression

I need to validate and email address when someone signs up.it should be something like                1234567@burnswin.edu.au

7 numbers @ and last part should be exactly like burnswin.edu.au
Please help me with a regular expression.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Not really a duplicate. This question has a stricter definition of a *valid email*. The OP could have at least made an attempt though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one

```
/^[0-9]{7}@burnswin\.edu\.au\z/
```

Comment: So `"bla 12345672@burnswin.edu.au bla"` is valid? ;)

Comment: you are right I will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could use..

```
$valid = preg_match("/^\d{7}@burnswin\.edu\.au\z/", $userSuppliedStr);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/76Hx0j).

The `\d` will match `0-9`, and the `{7}` will match 7 of them only.

The `^` matches the start of the string and the `\z` matches the end of the string.